# Unable to download event log from remote server

Tags: c#, .net, event-log

I am using below Microsoft code to download Event Logs from a remote server with IP.

When I try to execute code, it throws errors:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.'
```

The exception is very clear as I have not provided authentication in the code. I am executing this code from my local computer whereas IP is of a remote computer.

I want to know how to provide authentication information.

```
EventLog[] remoteEventLogs;

    remoteEventLogs = EventLog.GetEventLogs("xx.xxx.xx.xx");

    Console.WriteLine("Number of logs on computer: " + remoteEventLogs.Length);

    foreach(EventLog log in remoteEventLogs){
        Console.WriteLine("Log: " + log.Log);
    }
```

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966993/eventlogquery-reader-for-remote-computer